# I deleted .bash_history, now history isn't saved anymore (although I re-created it)

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, history

I have freshly installed a new copy of El Capitan. I accidently deleted .bash_history, so I just did a `touch .bash_history` again, hoping this would solve the problem of my bash history not being remembered when closing and re-opening the terminal.

But it didn't. And I have no idea why.

```
Macbuech:~ josh$ ~/.bash_history
-bash: /Users/josh/.bash_history: Permission denied
Macbuech:~ josh$ ls ~/.bash_history
/Users/josh/.bash_history
Macbuech:~ josh$ echo $HISTSIZE
500
Macbuech:~ josh$ echo $HISTFILESIZE
500
Macbuech:~ josh$ echo $HISTFILE
/Users/josh/.bash_sessions/9817540A-F021-4E1A-93A1-B322BC4738AB.historynew
Macbuech:~ josh$ echo $HISTTIMEFORMAT
```

I fiddled around a bit with `.bash_profile` to get some colors working, according to [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/05/improve-terminal-appearance-mac-os-x/):

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -GFh'
```

I removed all the stuff again to make sure the problem's not lying there. So here's my `.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

[This site](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3540) states that there may be a problem with RVM, and I tried adding a `.bash_logout` with `shell_session_update` in it, but no success.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Here's my complete env:

```
Macbuech:~ josh$ env
rvm_bin_path=/Users/josh/.rvm/bin
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
GEM_HOME=/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
IRBRC=/Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/.irbrc
TMPDIR=/var/folders/sq/92dr708946s01kttg916m6xm0000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.9AJd6SsR1y/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=361.1
MY_RUBY_HOME=/Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4
TERM_SESSION_ID=9817540A-F021-4E1A-93A1-B322BC4738AB
rvm_stored_umask=0022
USER=josh
_system_type=Darwin
rvm_path=/Users/josh/.rvm
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.gZZeyimp2O/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
rvm_prefix=/Users/josh
PATH=/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin:/Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/josh/.rvm/bin
rvm_loaded_flag=1
PWD=/Users/josh
_system_arch=x86_64
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
_system_version=10.11
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
rvm_version=1.26.11 (master)
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/josh
LOGNAME=josh
GEM_PATH=/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4:/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.2.4
rvm_user_install_flag=1
_system_name=OSX
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: What's the output for `ls -la ~/.bash_history` ? Maybe it's permissions problem? Here's my: `-rw-------  1 myusername  staff  10852 18 gru 20:41 /Users/myusername/.bash_history`

Comment: `$ ls -la ~/.bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 josh  staff     3B Dec 31 08:38 /Users/josh/.bash_history`

Comment: Did you restart the shell (or Terminal itself) after touching .bash_history?

Comment: For sure I did.

Comment: Could you temporarily remove your `~/.bash_profile`, start a new login shell, check if you have the same problem, report this in your OQ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I encountered the same problem after willingly deleting the .bash_history file.

The simple solution is to not only touch the file but also add some text - one or several line feeds are **not** sufficient:

```
echo "exit" >> ~/.bash_history
```

Then completely quit Terminal and reopen it. If you've saved all your work in all terminal sessions, you can also just

```
killall Terminal
```

---

**Update:**

I tried to replicate your environment in a 10.11 VM and it's indeed a problem with RVM: commenting out all rvm related lines in .profile and .bash_profile re-enables updates of the .bash_history file.

The .bash_logout file method (with the content *shell_session_update*) seems to work reliably here though. Just remember to **always** enter `exit` before closing a Terminal window or quitting Terminal. Without entering `exit` the history won't be updated.

Comment: And now the obvious question: why? Does the file need a new-line character or just any character?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I have a few lines in my history, but no new entries are added.

Comment: ls and exit, with no new line at the end: `ls\nexit`

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: How can this be done, disabling the `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim rename in to something else like `mv ~/.bash_profile ~/off.bash_profile` and relaunching Terminal (or `killall Terminal`)

Comment: aaah I can imagine what happened - when you open terminal and your login shell is bash, bash opens the file .bash_history. This opens internally a file descriptor pointing to the file with a inode.

The file is used by all bash shells in parallel.
Now when you delete the file from the command line within a bash session and you create it new, the file descriptor of bash is still open. But now there is a new history file with a different inode. bash still wants to write into the old file descriptor pointing to the old inode and can't.

Additionally the file is opened in append mode by bash.

Comment: Garex, this sounds interesting. How can this be solved?

Comment: Thanks for your update, klanomath. I could reproduce the problem: when commenting out the RVM stuff, the history seems to work as expected. This is rather annoying... But I will create a new question for that.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim Entering `exit` before leaving/closing Terminal/Terminal Window doesn't help? In my VM I got the same `env` output as yours (except my ruby version was a little bit older) and it worked.

Comment: I re-enabled the RVM stuff, and surprisingly, the history seems still to be working! Maybe commenting out RVM temporarily fixed the stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate the file with "nano", no with "touch". Run this command on terminal, in your home folder (/Users/Your-Username):

```
nano .bash_history
```

Type anything in the file (otherwise it won't be created), exit and save.

Hope this help.

Comment: How does this differ from the answer already given?

Comment: Get the expected result in a more simplified form, it is the only difference @patrix . Regards.

Comment: Doesn't change a thing, either. Is it maybe because I have different terminal windows open, with each having a few tabs?

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim That probably causes it, but could not be sure, I have not studied in detail the operation of ".bash_history" behavior  in osx "El Captain". What if I can say for sure is that each terminal session in osx, saves changes to the ".bash_history" file until you close the window or run the output command "exit", the file is not locked while the session is active.